# Multiple instances of corner pop up jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I am running a loop that will pick up any news items that should appear in a corner pop up on a website. I have the popup working great for the first item, but the second doesn't show. I've tried to do it by calling the function twice with a different delay & timeout on each one, so they should appear in sequence. I don't really do much jquery/javascript, so I don't understand why that doesn't work. I am guessing it is because the function is the same? Can anyone help me out? Code below!

TIA

```
<?php $delay = 50;
            $timeout = 3000;
            $i = 1;
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <?php if (have_rows('home_page_pop_up')) :
        
        while(have_rows('home_page_pop_up')) : the_row(); 
            if (get_sub_field('show_home') == 'Yes') :
                $showdate = get_sub_field('until_date');
                $today = date('Ymd');
        
        if ( $today <= $showdate ):
        
        ?>
        
        <script>
            
            jQuery.fn.cornerpopup({
            variant: 9,
            //displayOnce: true,
            slide: true,
            timeOut: <?php echo $timeout; ?>,
            delay: <?php echo $delay; ?>,
            link2: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/news-community/",
            header: "Recent News",
            text2: "<h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5><p><?php the_excerpt(); ?> ... <a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'>Read more</a></p>",
            button3: "View all News",
            stickToBottom: true,
            });


        </script>
            <?php endif;
        endif;
        $i++;
    $delay = $delay + 3000;
    $timeout = $timeout + 3000;
        endwhile;
        endif;
        endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Don't put the definition of `jQuery.fn.cornerpopup()` in the loop. Just do it once.

Comment: @Barmar but the OP is trying to run it with different content

Comment: Without knowing the plugin, does it support this? Have you gotten it to work trying the delay without using the PHP (aka just coding it directly)?

Comment: @epascarello I didn't look closely, I've never seen `jQuery.fn.XXX` used outside of defining the plugin, not calling it. The plugin would be called as `$(selector).cornerpopup()`

Comment: @Barmar I looked at the docs, OP is using it the way it is designed. I just do not think it is built to do what OP wants. Solution would be some sort of queue system or pick a better library to make toast messages.